# parse JSON string with escape sequences

Tags: json, string, parsing, groovy, escaping

I have string which is a JSON and inside that has another JSON as a string with escape sequences.

How can I parse the entire string as a JSON object ?

Here's a dummy example -:

```
'{"hello": "{\"my_name\":\"Robert\"}"}'
```

Final Output Desired -:

```
{"hello":{"my_name": "Robert"}}
```

I'm trying to parse this with groovy using the following code. But get compilation errors as there is another JSON inside the string with escape sequences.

```
import groovy.json.*;
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper;

def JsonSlurper slurper = new JsonSlurper();
def message = '{"hello": "{\"my_name\":\"Robert\"}"}';
def jsonMessage =  slurper.parseText(message);
println jsonMessage;
```

EDIT-:
The dummy example format cannot be changed statically, to double escape the backslash. It would need to be done using code.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks !!

Comment: You probably need to escape the backslash and not the quote, ie: `def message = '{"hello": "{\\"my_name\\":\\"Robert\\"}"}';`

Comment: Yupe agreed. But that also needs to be done using code. Cannot manually change the string to add another \. This is just a dummy example but actually, the payload message comes in this format. Do you have any suggestions about how to achieve this using code ?

Comment: What is the source of the JSON? Your JSON is already properly quoted and will work. What's _not_ properly quoted in _groovy_ is your string in the example. Quoting the string properly in _groovy_ will not change the original but will make it identical to what your source provides.

Comment: @cfrick Source of the JSON is a Kafka message that will be read by the groovy script as a string. Hence I've quoted the incoming message as a string in the example above. 
`def JsonSlurper slurper = new JsonSlurper(); def jsonMessage = slurper.parseText(payload); println jsonMessage;`
Here's what the actual code will look like and breaks (compilation error) when that string `payload` is passed to the slurper method.

Comment: Then please add the compilation error you get and the actual code you are using. Your current question in the attempt to simplifiy the problem creates a different problem.

Comment: @ishanrohatgi09, + add the original message from kafka.